# cURL authorization on ASP.NET website

Tags: asp.net, curl, authorization

Can anyone help me to figure out what am I doing wrong?

**What do we have:**

- A website where I need to log in via cURL.
- Credentials of two accounts that have to be logged in.

**What did I get**

I managed to log in only one account via cURL, but can't log in the second one. However I can log in with both of them via browser.

**What did I try**

this one works fine

```
curl --verbose --location -b ~/cookie.txt -c ~/cookie.txt 
     --data "tbLogin=login1&tbPassword=password1&btSubmit=Войти"
     http://online.tmtr.ru/login.aspx
```

this one doesn't

```
curl --verbose --location -b ~/cookie.txt -c ~/cookie.txt 
     --data "tbLogin=login2&tbPassword=password2&btSubmit=Войти"
     http://online.tmtr.ru/login.aspx
```

The only difference is in the logins and passwords.

I also tried to use separate cookie files for each account.

**Here are the logs**

Working account:

```
* About to connect() to online.tmtr.ru port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 109.73.3.134...
* connected
* Connected to online.tmtr.ru (109.73.3.134) port 80 (#0)
> POST /login.aspx HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.26.0
> Host: online.tmtr.ru
> Accept: */*
> Cookie: _some_cookie_data_
> Content-Length: 59
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 59 out of 59 bytes
* additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Location: /main.aspx
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
< X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
* Replaced cookie _some_cookie_data_
< Set-Cookie: _some_cookie_data_
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Wed, 02 Dec 2015 13:49:39 GMT
< Content-Length: 129
<
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host online.tmtr.ru left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://online.tmtr.ru/main.aspx'
* Violate RFC 2616/10.3.3 and switch from POST to GET
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host (nil)
* Connected to (nil) (109.73.3.134) port 80 (#0)
> GET /main.aspx HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.26.0
> Host: online.tmtr.ru
> Accept: */*
> Cookie: _some_cookie_data_
>
* additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
< X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Wed, 02 Dec 2015 13:49:39 GMT
< Content-Length: 150950
<

<!-- Here goes the html of the page with user's account -->
```

Problem account:

```
* About to connect() to online.tmtr.ru port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 109.73.3.134...
* connected
* Connected to online.tmtr.ru (109.73.3.134) port 80 (#0)
> POST /login.aspx HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.26.0
> Host: online.tmtr.ru
> Accept: */*
> Cookie: _some_cookie_data_
> Content-Length: 56
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
* upload completely sent off: 56 out of 56 bytes
* additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Location: /main.aspx
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
< X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
* Replaced cookie _some_cookie_data_
< Set-Cookie: _some_cookie_data_
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Wed, 02 Dec 2015 13:45:10 GMT
< Content-Length: 129
<
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host online.tmtr.ru left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://online.tmtr.ru/main.aspx'
* Violate RFC 2616/10.3.3 and switch from POST to GET
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host (nil)
* Connected to (nil) (109.73.3.134) port 80 (#0)
> GET /main.aspx HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.26.0
> Host: online.tmtr.ru
> Accept: */*
> Cookie: _some_cookie_data_
>
* additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Cache-Control: private
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Location: /error.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/main.aspx
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
< X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Wed, 02 Dec 2015 13:45:10 GMT
<
* Ignoring the response-body
* Connection #0 to host (nil) left intact
* Issue another request to this URL: 'http://online.tmtr.ru/error.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/main.aspx'
* Re-using existing connection! (#0) with host (nil)
* Connected to (nil) (109.73.3.134) port 80 (#0)
> GET /error.aspx?aspxerrorpath=/main.aspx HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.26.0
> Host: online.tmtr.ru
> Accept: */*
> Cookie: _some_cookie_data_
>
* additional stuff not fine transfer.c:1037: 0 0
* HTTP 1.1 or later with persistent connection, pipelining supported
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: private
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
< X-AspNet-Version: 2.0.50727
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Wed, 02 Dec 2015 13:45:10 GMT
< Content-Length: 405
<

<!-- Here goes the html of the page with error -->
```

As I mentioned before, I can successfully log in with both of the accounts via the browser.

How can I figure out why the server rejects one of the accounts via curl but doesn't via browser?

I also tried to send request via [Postman extention](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop) for the Chrome browser and it works just fine too.
[image]

Comment: It might be because when you are logging into the second account, you are tell cURL to use the cookie file which has cookies from the first account.  Maybe their login page checks to see if you are already logged in based on cookies and then just redirects rather than logging you in to the second account?  If you try the second account with a different cookie file does it work?

Comment: I tried separate cookie file for the problem account: `curl --verbose --location -b ~/anotherCookie.txt -c ~/anotherCookie.txt --data "tbLogin=login&tbPassword=password&btSubmit=Войти" http://online.tmtr.ru/login.aspx`

Comment: I can't understand what am I missing. I can log in both accounts via browser in any order. If I'm building wrong cURL request then why one of the accounts is able to log in? It should not log in too, right? Looks like the browser handles responses different way rather than cURL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've contacted with the owner of that site and it turned out that there is a custom validation of the "accept language" header. I didn't send this header at all. I don't know why some requests passed validation and some not, but after I added this header to my requests all gone well :)

Answer (score 0):

It is because, when you do login using the second account, it is using the cookie from the previously saved cookie. And when server sees a valid cookie, it just redirect you into a different location (or something else decided by the server).

To overcome this, just flush the cookie file before the second curl.

```
echo ''> ~/cookie.txt
```

Comment: Yes, I didn't mention that I flushed the cookie, that makes no difference. And the order of accounts doesn't matter, so if I'm trying to log in the problem account first I get the same result.